# How can I delete the recommendation section of my LinkedIn profile?

Tags: linkedin

A company I partner with is asking me to delete the recommendation section entirely from my profile. They can't even have it as an option on my profile. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

LI lets you show/hide individual recommendations.
(Copied from LI help)

1. Click the Me icon at the top of your LinkedIn homepage
2. Click View profile
3. Scroll to the Recommendations section and click the  Edit icon in the top right corner
4. On the Received tab of the pop-up window, locate the recommendation you want to hide or unhide
5. Switch the toggle to Show or Hide
6. Click Save